# get string of values in excel diagram

Tags: string, excel, vba

The values in a `SeriesCollection` can be set as

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='Sheet1'!$F$3:$F$403"
```

I want to know the string in order ot modify it, however it can only be get as an variant and can not be converted to a string

```
Dim values As Variant
Dim valuesStr As String
values = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(m).Values
valueStr = Cstr(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(m).Values) ' fails!
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quick solution (without giving it much thought) - Why not just loop through the `values` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`valueStr = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(m).Formula`

That will return a string like:

`=SERIES("series_name",,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4,1)`

You should then be able to use some string functions to parse out the address for the values range.

Otherwise, following John's suggestion, do:

```
Dim values as Variant
Dim v as Variant
values = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(m).Values
For each v in values
    'Do something to the values here...'
Next
```

Comment: I am not interested in the values itself, but `Formula` solved my problem.